# Need to divide/manage array

Tags: php, arrays, divide

I need to change a two-dimensional array to a three-dimensional array irrespective of the lengths of the array:

I have the following:

```
array(89) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { [0]=>"aaa" [1]=>"bbb"[2]=>"ccc" [3]=>"ddd" [4]=>"eee" } 
    [1]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }
    [2]=> array(5) { [0]=>"aaa" [1]=>"bbb"[2]=>"ccc" [3]=>"ddd" [4]=>"eee" } 
    [3]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }
    [4]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }
...}
```

I need

```
array (?) {   
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { [0]=>"aaa" [1]=>"bbb"[2]=>"ccc" [3]=>"ddd" [4]=>"eee" }   
        [1]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }}
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { [0]=>"aaa" [1]=>"bbb"[2]=>"ccc" [3]=>"ddd" [4]=>"eee" }  
        [1]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }
        [2]=> array(5) { [0]=>"blablabla" [1]=>"blablabla" [2]=>"blablabla" [3]=>"blablabla" [4]=>"blablabla" }}
    ...}
```

'blablabla' can be any length and format, but 'aaa', 'bbb', ... is the same in all arrays. need to array begins with 'aaa'

Comment: Can we see the code that builds your 2D array? (Aside: please don't write in all-lower-case or all-upper-case - as you can see from your two questions, people will edit this).

Comment: You have same keys for multiple rows.. Not possible

Comment: im not using same keys

Comment: @big.data You are not but you need your data to be: `[0]=> array(2) {`, `[0]=> array(5) {` the `0` key is repeating on the same level.

Comment: @i-can-has-cheezburger i still not understand ... where key is repeating on the SAME level

Comment: @big.data Ah you indented the array, see? Formatting matters. Now could you explain why the first level has 2 array while the second has 3? Is there a logic behind this?

Comment: @i-can-has-cheezburger 'blablabla' can be any length and format, but 'aaa', 'bbb', ... is the same in all arrays. need to array begins with 'aaa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple actually, all you need is one `foreach()`:

```
$i=-1; //this will increment on first loop so we set it to -1
$key_to_find = $array[0][0]; //storing the 'aaa' value
$result = array();       
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    //checking if 'aaa' equals to the first value, if yes increment $i to 0
    ($val[0]==$key_to_find)?$i++:'';
    //save the whole array bunch
    $result[$i][] = $val;
}

print_r($result);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/147165)**

Comment: @big.data You're welcome, please mark this question as solved by ticking at the left if it helped ^-^